# Cannot find M+ fonts I installed

Tags: fonts

I downloaded [M+ Fonts](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/mplus-fonts), and installed using its script to /usr/share/fonts/X11/mplus.

fc-cache shows `/usr/share/fonts/X11/mplus: caching, new cache contents: 30 fonts, 0 dirs`.  But I cannot find the font any where. I have allowed bitmap fonts in fontconfig.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the .ttf file in your home, particularly in the .fonts folder (and create the folder if it's not there).

Asuming you have your font (`myfont.ttf`) in your Downloads folder (`~/Downloads` or `/home/**yourname**/Downloads` -which is the same thing written in a different way-), the commands you should run are:

```
mkdir -p ~/.fonts  
cp ~/Downloads/myfont.ttf ~/.fonts/
```

Done!

Modern versions of Ubuntu (from 12.04 and on) doesn't need you to run a font-cache update. The system will pickup your new font in a pinch. :)